# How to test this method? (RSpec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

```
def is_doctor
    user = User.find_by(role: 'doctor')
    "Name: #{user.name} | Email: #{user.email}| isActive: #{user.is_active}"  
end
```

Something like this, but I don't know how to implement it correctly ↓

```
context 'test' do
  #it { expect(user.is_doctor).to eq("Taras") }
end
```

Comment: I wanted the test to check something like this => `it { expect (user.name). to eq("Taras") }` It is not possible to read the value from the method into the test. I don't know how to write correctly.

Comment: `is_doctor` returns a string, you can't read a variable form it. either test for the whole string or use `expect(is_doctor).to match /user.name/`

Comment: Thanks! But gives an error NoMethodError: undefined method `name'.

Comment: build the object first, you can use factory girl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `doctor?` is an instance method on a `User` model + you're using [Faker](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker) which might help you a lot.

```rb
# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def doctor?
    return 'Not a doc' unless role == 'doctor'

    "Name: #{name} | Email: #{email}| isActive: #{is_active}"
  end
end

# specs/models/user_spec.rb
describe User, type: :model do
  context 'with instance method' do

    describe '#doctor?' do
      subject { user. doctor? }

      context 'with a doctor' do
        let(:user) { create(:user, role: 'doctor') }

        it 'includes name' do
          expect(subject).to include("Name: #{user.name}")
        end
        
        it 'includes email' do
          expect(subject).to include("Email: #{email}")
        end

        it 'includes is_active' do
          expect(subject).to include("isActive: #{is_active}")
        end
      end

      context 'without doctor' do
        let(:user) { create(:user, role: 'foo') }

        it 'has static response' do
          expect(subject).to eq('Not a doc')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `is_...` is not the correct way to write it. Best practices say `...?`